# Sphero TwoPhonesOneBall sample compiler error

Tags: java, android, sphero-api, sphero

I imported the samples of Sphero-Android SDK to my workspace. TwoPhonesOneBall project gives compiler errors. In ConnectionActivity.java class, the following imports cannot be resolved.

//...some imports

```
import orbotix.multiplayer.LocalMultiplayerClient;
import orbotix.multiplayer.MultiplayerControlStrategy;
import orbotix.multiplayer.MultiplayerGame;
import orbotix.multiplayer.RemotePlayer;
```

//...imports

How can I fix it? Since these classes don't exist, I didn't come up with a solution. I searched the net but I couldn't find similar problem. By the way,the same problem also occurs in MultiplayerLobby application.

Comment: Do you have RobotLibrary.jar in your build path?  If not, you could try following the instructions at https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-Android-SDK

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes i checked it, RobotLibrary.jar is in my buildpath. Otherwise the other imports would give compilation errors too. Besides,when I look into jar, I don't see any packages starts with "orbotix.multiplayer", so I makes sense the project can't resolve them.

Comment: any clue? so am i the only person in the planet that gets compiler error with this project?